# Change navbar height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using the gae boilerplate for my application.
I want to change the size of the navbar component but I don't find the attribute to do it.
I have already searched the responses from others subjects but I don't find the attribute to change the height in the css or less bootstrap files.

Is there anyone who has already used the gae boilerplate and can give me an answer ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have code to show us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For twitter bootstrap, set the `height` or `min-height` property of the `.navbar-inner` class.

For example:

```
.navbar-inner {
    height: 80px;  
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sv4Wj/14)

Comment: If I do that the collapse function for bootstrap responsive stops working properly.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you would have to account for that on a lower breakpoint.

Comment: could you update your fiddle with corrected CSS import?

Comment: @dbrin Updated. It is probably outdated now, though.

Comment: cool, thanks! its almost right, the collapse button is not showing, but the height is shrunk. By the way if you have form elements in the navbar this wont be enough to shrink them.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to change the padding on the navbar class and the nav class for lists:

```
.navbar .brand,
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer only worked partially for me on Bootstrap 2.12. This worked better for me (where .widget is the class of the items I want to have smaller navbars on):

```
.navbar .brand,
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    padding: 8px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.navbar-inner{
    min-height:16px;
}
.navbar .navbar-inner .brand {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.widget .navbar .navbar-inner .nav .dropdown a {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.widget .navbar .navbar-inner a.btn {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```